# How to use android download service in the gingerbread frame work layer?

Tags: android

I need the instance of `DownloadManager` class in the gingerbread framework layer. I tried this,

```
mgr=(DownloadManager) getSystemService(context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
```

But it is not working. How can i download a file using the download manager from the framework layer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> it is not working

On StackOverflow, people will think more highly of you if you provide a reasonable set of symptoms.

> how can i download a file using the download manager from the framework layer?

[Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Internet/Download) demonstrating the use of `DownloadManager`.